# How WEB APIs are implemented into JS?

Tags: javascript, api, browser, built-in

WEB APIs like a DOM are not a part of built-in JS objects, so how it is possible that I can use them without importing them? What inner mechanism is responsible for that?

Comment: Look up “host environment” for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *are* builtins, provided by the environment. They're just not native EcmaScript objects, they're host objects.